# How do I transfer saved games to another pc?

Tags: fifa-11

I have been playing FIFA 11 on my friend's laptop for a long time.  Now, I have a new laptop. How do I transfer all my saved manager mode games to my laptop?

Is it possible to transfer my profile as well?

Answer (score 1):

There should be a folder in your Documents directory by the name of FIFA 11. Find all the files in there, those are related to your profile. Copy them and use them on your new laptop.

On occasions, there are sub folders within that directory by the name of your profile. I don't have FIFA 11 currently installed to confirm it. FIFA 12 has no such folder, but other games like NFS have separate sub directories for each user profile.